# Javascript: Save a variable after if else

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have two clickable divs for selecting gender. now i'm trying to save the selection via javascript to a variable to use it later. I'm new to javascript so i'm struggling to find an approach. This is my html (bootstrap):

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 heading-center"></div>
<div class=" col-md-3 col-md-offset-2 div-gender" id="woman">
    <a href="#seite2">
        <img src="img/woman.png">
    </a>
</div>
<div class=" col-md-3  col-md-offset-2 div-gender" id="man">
    <a href="#seite2">
        <img src="img/man.png">
    </a>
</div>
```

**Edit :**
divs made clickable using css:

```
 .div - gender a
  {
     display: block;
  }
```

Comment: you have to make an attempt first and the come here if you're stuck. Folks here won't just write the code for you, that won't help you learn in the long run.

Comment: And note that that CSS doesn't make anything more clickable than it was to start with. In fact, that CSS is invalid. `-` isn't a combinator. There's `+` (adjacent sibling) and `~` (general sibling), but no `-`.

Comment: oh, should be .div-gender a

Answer (score 1):

*[playground](http://jsbin.com/IfeZUnEt/1/edit)*

```
var userGender;            // will hold the gender
var genderDIV = document.getElementsByClassName('div-gender');

function storeGender(event){
  event.preventDefault();  // Prevent default anchor behavior
  userGender = this.id ;   // Sets Gender to the clicked DIV ID
  alert( userGender );     // Test only
} 
                           // Assign click handler to all .div-gender
                           // The listener data callback will be our storeGender
                           // function that will capture the event and the 'this'
                           // reference to the clicked element (see fn above).
for(var i=0; i<genderDIV.length; i++){
    genderDIV[i].addEventListener('click', storeGender, false);
}
```

Comment: the alert is not technically neccessary (but I assume OP knows how to remove it)

Comment: thanks! Unfortunately, this only works when I delete the img tags in the divs. I tried it with text instead of the images, and it worked fine. What's the problem with the img tags and the javacript-code?

Comment: @PetePeterson if it does not work for you, it does not mean the answer is not correct ;) Here's an example with images: http://jsbin.com/IfeZUnEt/3/edit I cannot even imagine what could your issue be...

Comment: I did not say that it is not correct ;)sorry for that. But there's a problem with the img tag and i also have no idea why that shouldn't work. Even more scary is, that it works fine when I put it on JSFiddle ....:/